# Velocity-time-distance problem

Tags: kinematics, projectile, conventions

In my book the formula for the $y$-component of velocity during the upward projectile motion is given:

$$V_y=V_{iy}-gt$$

and next to it the formula for $y$-component of velocity during the downward projectile motion is given, differed only by a conjugate,

$$V_y=V_{iy}+gt$$

I think it must have been:

$$V_y=gt$$

since $V_{iy}=0$ at the maximum height of projectile. I took time arbitrarily same for both conditions i.e. $t$.

Am I right?

Comment: I don't know what is correct to put as title. If anyone could do it for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's customary to use small $v$ for velocity (but not mandatory).

Notations like $v_y$ and $v_{iy}$ make little sense without defining them. Here it *implies* the velocity component *along* the $y$-axis but without specifying this axis nothing makes much sense either.

So I'll define the $y$-axis as a vertical axis, pointing upwards. This *sense* is important too, as we'll define the *scalar* of any vector pointing in that direction as positive and the *scalar* of any vector pointing in the opposite direction as negative:

[image: y-axis.]

Having cleared this up, the expression:

$$v_y=v_{iy}-gt,$$

now makes perfect sense because $\vec{g}$ points downwards. The index *iy* of course refers to *initial*.

It's also the **only** expression (for speed) we need. Assuming $\vec{v_{iy}}$ pointed upward then $v_y$ is positive as long as:

$$v_{iy}>gt,$$

after which the object starts falling back to Earth and $v_y$ becomes negative in accordance with the convention agreed upon higher up.

Note also that if $\vec{v_{iy}}$ was pointing downwards (an object thrown downwards from a 
building for instance) the expression for $v_y$ still returns the correct result.

The expression can be further generalised as:

$$v_y=v_{iy}+at.$$

For numerical computations, the correct signs then have to be assigned to the values of $v_{iy}$ and $a$, in accordance with the directions of the vectors $\vec{v_{iy}}$ and $\vec{a}$.

Comment: If I didn't get you wrong you are saying that the formula $$V_y=V_{iy}-gt$$ can be used for upward as well as downward motion?

Comment: @SufyanNaeem: yes. Mathematically that's a *only* question of sign, *provided* you've set up a *frame of reference* (here just one $y$-axis). Get used to doing that because most mechanical problems require it.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem: I'm making a small edit, further clarifying.

Comment: Although I have gotten what sort of your reference frame is but still I wish you add a image of the reference frame you are talking about along with the velocity vectors. I am dealing with this type of problem first time where the only axis is $y$-axis.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem: will add it.

Comment: When you said $V_y=V_{iy}+at$ you mean; when solving numerical problems $V_{iy}$ will automatically be zero and the equation would become, $V_y=gt$. Isn't so? For example in the case of dropping an object from over a building.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32930/discussion-between-gert-and-sufyan-naeem).